# Java Hashmap -- Key Value Pairs from Stdin to HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, stdin

Java Hashmap -- Is it possible to read key value pairs from standard input directly into a hash map structure?

Say user types in

```
4 3 
1 1
3 2
2 2 
4 3
```

My idea is to do some sort of loop with repeated put.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried? Are you stuck? What is your question?

Comment: "My idea is to do some sort of loop with repeated put." --- That's a good idea.  Why don't you try doing that?  If you get stuck, come back and ask a question about the problem you're having.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really sure how you want to add them, as int's or Strings, but remember they have to be Objects.

```
class Inp {
    public void scan() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        while (true) {
            String sr = sc.nextLine();
            String[] tk = sr.split(" ");
            Integer key = 0, value = 0;
            try {
                key = Integer.parseInt(tk[0]);
                value = Integer.parseInt(tk[1]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                break;
            }
            map.put(key,value);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Inp inp = new Inp();
       inp.scan();

    }
}
```

VERRRRYYYY long winded but you get the idea.  Put in anything besides an integer to break out of the loop.  Didn't know what you wanted.

Comment: why don't you `map.put(key, value)` within the `try` block? This way you could also declare the two integers within the try-block and keep their scope as small as possible ... actually you could do all the 'logic' within the try-block. would do no harm...

Comment: sure why not.  I just threw it up.  I just wanted to make sure I highlighted the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: And -1 because...does it not work?

Comment: And you should notify the user why the input loop was ended. Not just swallow the Exception. Like `System.out.println("Invalid input.");` ... The downvote's not by me. But could be because you answered an *"SO is no coding service question."*

Comment: why would something besides an integer break out of your while loop? would a problem with types necessarily change the boolean value? and your code definitely works thanks. I guess i didn't realize how much there was to this question. I was looking to store the integers as integers and just picked a hash map as my guess for the most appropriate data structure. . .

Comment: I got hosed with a -1, how about accepting this answer.

Comment: sorry! literally, my first question on this website... thanks for the help.